# c++ - как считывать файлы большого размера?

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Нужно скопировать файл с одной дирректории в другую.

Написал программу, в которой есть два объекта типа FILE, с помощью fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_END) получаем размер, а чтение и запись происходят с помощью fread и fwrite.

Файл читаю блоками по 256 байт, вот код:

```
   // Переходим в конец файла
   fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_END);
   // Размер файла
   unsigned int m_file_size = ftell(fin);
   rewind(fin);

   // BLOCK_SIZE = 256 байт
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_file_size / BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fin);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fout);
   }

   // Дальше считываю остаток файла теми же fread и fwrite
```

Собственно, программа работает корректно с небольшими файлами (пробовал копировать файл размером 1 Гб - скопировал нормально). Однако при копировании фала размером 2.5 Гб. - выходной файл получается больше по размеру, чем входной.

Сам думаю, что проблема как раз в fseek, fread и fwrite, так как они работают с интом, который больше 2.147 Гб. не вместит.

Вопрос такой: что нужно использовать вместо этих трех функций, чтобы программа корректно работала для больших файлов?

**UPDATE 1**

Код с открытием файла:

```
// File to read
FILE *fin;
// File to write
FILE *fout;

const int BLOCK_SIZE = 256;
unsigned char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
if(!(fin = fopen(file_from_path.toStdString().c_str(), "rb")) == NULL &&
   !(fout = fopen(file_to_path.toStdString().c_str(), "wb")) == NULL) {

    // The end of the file
    fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_END);
    // Get size of the file
    unsigned int m_file_size = ftell(fin);
    // Go to start
    rewind(fin);

    // Read and write by "BLOCK_SIZE" bytes
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_file_size / BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) {
        // Read "BLOCK_SIZE" bytes to buffer
        fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fin);
        // Write "BLOCK_SIZE" bytes
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fout);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем предварительно получать размер файла? Почему бы не просто читать его блоками до тех пор, пока файл не кончится, благо fread возвращает количество реально прочитанных элементов?

Comment: @Yaant Дело в том, что в программе используется прогресс бар, отображающий текущий прогресс, который я узнаю как cur_position / m_file_size (от 0 до 1)

Comment: Привидите пожалуйста весь код: который включает открытие файлов.

Comment: @Unick Добавил в вопросе

Comment: У вас точно *выходной файл получается больше по размеру, чем входной*, а не наоборот?

Comment: Из-за прерываний `fread` может прочитать меньше чем `BLOCK_SIZE`. В этом случае у вас в фаил запишется мусор от предыдущей операции чтения. Нужно всегда проверять сколько прочитал `fread`.

Comment: @Harry Да, выходной примерно на 300 Мб больше входного

Comment: А вы не пробовали скопилировать программу под 64 битную архитектуру?

Comment: @Arnial Хорошо, попробую реализовать проверку
Хотя странно, что прерывания возникают только в случае копирования файлов больше 2 Гб

Comment: Что-то я не могу найти тут не то что Qt, но даже и c++.

Comment: @alexolut Qt есть, но чтобы не засорять пример, взял только работу с файлами. Вы думаете, что лучше использовать ifstream и ofsteam?

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy я думаю, что у вопроса должны быть релевантные метки, т.е. убрать [tag:c++] и [tag:qt] и поставить [tag:c].

Comment: @alexolut Но данный пример работает в  C++, так что можно убрать только Qt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку в стандарте работа идет с `int` да `long`, каковые в большинстве своем 32-битные, я бы использовал нестандартные функции операционной системы или соответствующие расширения компилятора.

Если это VC++, то можно использовать всяческие нестандартные расширения - функции типа `_fseeki64`, `_ftelli64` и иже с ними - например, см. [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx).

Кстати, вот это

```
    fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fin);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fout);
```

некорректно. С чего вы решили, что у вас размер кратен размеру буфера?

```
    int readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fin);
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), readed, fout);
```

правильнее. Но по-хорошему, надо еще и возврат записи проверять.

Ага, вот причина большего размера: `fseek/ftell` при некорректной работе возвращают -1, что у вас для вашего `unsigned m_file_size` трансформируется в 4 Гигабайта. Результат понятен...

Вот работающий код. Правда, надо все равно проверять возврат всех функций...

```
// File to read
FILE *fin;
// File to write
FILE *fout;

const int BLOCK_SIZE = 256;
unsigned char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
if(!(fin = fopen("data.in", "rb")) == NULL &&
   !(fout = fopen("data.out", "wb")) == NULL) {

    // The end of the file
    _fseeki64(fin, 0, SEEK_END);
    // Get size of the file
    long long m_file_size = _ftelli64(fin);
    // Go to start
    _fseeki64(fin, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read and write by "BLOCK_SIZE" bytes
    for(size_t i = 0; i <= m_file_size / BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) {
        int readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), BLOCK_SIZE, fin);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), readed, fout);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

}
```

Comment: Использую Qt Creator и MinGW, хотелось бы сделать программу платформонезависимой... 
А функции с суфиксом 64 будут работать с файлами, размер которых больше  2^64?

Comment: Для того они и предназначены - чтоб работать с размерами больше 32 бит.

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy А у Вас действительно есть файлы размером в десятки эксабайт?

Comment: @Yaant нет :D Но все же _fseeki64 и _ftelli64 - это расширения, хотелось бы без них.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: @Harry Да, я потом считываю остаток, либо весь файл целиком, если его размер меньше BLOCK_SIZE.
Я все таки не уверен, правильно ли я все понял: fseek/ftell работают некорректно, так как размер файла больше 2^32? То есть их не стоит использовать в принципе...

Comment: Да, на больших файлах они не работают, сообщая об этом возвращаемым значением -1, которое вы не проверяете. См. работающий код в ответе.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, теперь я со всем разобрался. Вопрос закрыт.